# Где допущена ошибка jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код:

```
    $('.content__menu a').on('click', function () {
    if (this.value == 'all') {
        $('.tile').removeClass('.disabled-tile');
    } else{
        var elems = $('.tile[data-type="'+this.value+'"]');
        $('.tile').not(elems).hide();
        elems.addClass('.disabled-tile');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<nav class="content__menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu__item menu__item_active" value="all">Все страны</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="culture">Культура</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="extreme">Экстрим</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="atmos">Атмосфера</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="people">Люди</a>
</nav>
<section class="section__box">
    <article class="tile disabled-tile" data-type="culture">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-1">
                <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Cuba</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="tile__slide cuba_slide-2">
                <div class="tile__slide_text">Хэмингуэй, став весьма знаменитым, 
                            естественно, мог выбрать любое место в мире. 
                            Почему же он 22 года прожил в Гаване? Потому что это свобода!
                </div>
                <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-3">
                <a class="fancybox slide__btn-zoom lazy" href="img/cuba.jpg" alt="Cuba">
                    <img src="img/icon_zoom.svg" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">
                </a>
                <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-4">
                <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slide__btn-zoom" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3jkHdoHe1kc?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1">
                <img src="img/icon_play.svg" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">
                </a>
                <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="tile" data-type="extreme">
                    <div class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg rus_slide-1">
                            <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Russia</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg rus_slide-2">
                            <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Russia</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="tile tile--width2 tile--height2" data-type='culture'>
                    <h2 class="tile--width2__country-name">Latin America</h2>
                    <div class="tile--width2__features">
                        <span class="tile--width2__features-item">1. Honduras</span>
                        <span class="tile--width2__features-item">2. Columbia</span>
                        <span class="tile--width2__features-item">3. Panama</span>
                        <span class="tile--width2__features-item">4. Brazil</span>
                        <span class="tile--width2__features-item">5. Peru</span>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="tile" data-type="atmos">
                    <div class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg eng_slide-1">
                            <h2 class="tile__slide_country">England</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg eng_slide-2">
                            <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">England</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="tile" data-type="atmos">
                    <div class="owl-carousel">
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg norw_slide-1">
                            <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Norway</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg norw_slide-2">
                            <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Norway</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

Но при клике - пропадают все элементы **.tile**, где тут ошибка?

Comment: консоль.лог почему то выдает ".tile[data-type="undefined"]"

Comment: `$(this).attr('value')` !== `this.value`. Использй аттрибут, а не переменную.

Comment: @Dimava не совсем понимаю что и как изменить. Пробовал по разному заменить значение. Можете, пожалуйста, поподробней?

Comment: Попробуй использовать для `<a value="smth">` `$(this).attr('value')` вместо `this.value`.

Comment: @Dimava извиняюсь за нозойливость и мою тупость. Заменяю на if $(this).attr('value') ==  'all' {} выдает ошибку

Comment: Приведите пример вашего HTML кода, а то так можно вечно гадать, что за мистика происходит :)

Comment: @fremail да, конечно, сейчас добавлю)

Comment: @fremail добавил

Comment: @fremail так, скорей всего, дует лучше) https://jsfiddle.net/atomr/44ymszx1/

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что в elems ничего нет. Недавно столкнулся с похожей проблемой, что jQuery не находит элемент по атрибутам. Тут выхода 2: либо использовать классы вместо data-type и сделать код JS элегантным `var elems = $('.tile.tile_'+this.value)`, либо пробегаться в цикле по каждому элементу .tile и сравнивать их data-type вручную

Comment: @fremail сейчас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.value` возвращает значение свойство(property)"value",которое не оределено, а не аттрибут(attribute)"value",определённый в HTML.

Замена `this.value` на `$(this).attr('value')` решает эту проблему.

ущё ошибка - вы `.hide()`-ом элементы прячете, а `.show()`-ом не показываете.

```js
$('.content__menu a').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('value'));
  if ($(this).attr('value') == 'all') {
    $('.tile').removeClass('.disabled-tile').show();
  } else {
    var elems = $('.tile[data-type="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]');
    $('.tile').not(elems).hide();
    elems.addClass('.disabled-tile').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="content__menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu__item menu__item_active" value="all">Все страны</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="culture">Культура</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="extreme">Экстрим</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="atmos">Атмосфера</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu__item" value="people">Люди</a>
</nav>
<section class="section__box">
  <article class="tile disabled-tile" data-type="culture">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-1">
        <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Cuba</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide cuba_slide-2">
        <div class="tile__slide_text">Хэмингуэй, став весьма знаменитым, естественно, мог выбрать любое место в мире. Почему же он 22 года прожил в Гаване? Потому что это свобода!
        </div>
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-3">
        <a class="fancybox slide__btn-zoom lazy" href="img/cuba.jpg" alt="Cuba">
          <img src="img/icon_zoom.svg" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">
        </a>
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg cuba_slide-4">
        <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe slide__btn-zoom" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3jkHdoHe1kc?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1">
          <img src="img/icon_play.svg" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">
        </a>
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Cuba</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="tile" data-type="extreme">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg rus_slide-1">
        <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Russia</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg rus_slide-2">
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Russia</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="tile tile--width2 tile--height2" data-type='culture'>
    <h2 class="tile--width2__country-name">Latin America</h2>
    <div class="tile--width2__features">
      <span class="tile--width2__features-item">1. Honduras</span>
      <span class="tile--width2__features-item">2. Columbia</span>
      <span class="tile--width2__features-item">3. Panama</span>
      <span class="tile--width2__features-item">4. Brazil</span>
      <span class="tile--width2__features-item">5. Peru</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="tile" data-type="atmos">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg eng_slide-1">
        <h2 class="tile__slide_country">England</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg eng_slide-2">
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">England</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="tile" data-type="atmos">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg norw_slide-1">
        <h2 class="tile__slide_country">Norway</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tile__slide slide-mainbg norw_slide-2">
        <h3 class="slide__footer-country-name">Norway</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, очень помогли)

Comment: последняя ремарка, а как сбросить .disabled при переключении на другой пункт? А то при переключении класс .disabled остается на тех блоках, где был ранее

Comment: `$('.tile').not(elems).hide()` `.removeClass('.disabled-tile')`

Comment: в конце через еще один else добавить?

Comment: разобрался. в .removeClass('.disabled-tile') нужно убрать точку что бы получилось так - .removeClass('disabled-tile'). Благодарю вас еще раз и простите на мою назойливость)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:

```
 $('.content__menu a').on('click', function () {
    if (this.value == 'all') {
        $('.tile').removeClass('.disabled-tile');
    } else{
        var elems = $('.tile[data-type="'+this.value+'"]');
        **$('.tile').removeClass('.disabled-tile');**
        elems.addClass('.disabled-tile');
    }
})
```

Comment: к сожалению - ноль реакции. Элемент обазначается так - <article class="tile" data-type="extreme"> Тут же все правильно?